# I am not getting the Image from URL?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an URL and I want to convert into the bitmap but I'm not getting the o/p . I applied some way to sort this thing but still not getting anything .

I search the solution in previous answer on Stack Overflow but I got stuck from it also.  What I am doing :

```
URL url = new URl("http://www.XYZ.com/image.jpg");
```

and put this thing into the

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(_ _ _);
```

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream()); I tried this but failed

Answer (score 0):

```
private Drawable loadImageFromWeb(String url) {
        try {   
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: src name - the name of the source for the bitmap(can be null)

Answer (score 0):

how about this? it works when I tried.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.XYZ.com/image.jpg");
Object content = url.getContent();
InputStream is = (InputStream) content;
//drawable
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
//bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: InputStream is = (InputStream) content; this line gives me the error ... I tried all the sample ... check the permission also but not getting the solution

Answer (score 0):

A long but functional solving

```
    try 
    {    
        InputStream inn = OpenConnection(URL);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inn);
        inn.close();    
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {    
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String url) {
       InputStream in = null;
       int response = -1;

       URL url = new URL(url);
       URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

       try {
           HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
           httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
           httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
           httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
           httpConn.connect();
           response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

           if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
           }
       } 
       catch (Exception ex) 
       {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    return in;
  }
```